# Counterfeit coins problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory

You have 1000 large bags of small coins. In one of the thousand bags, all the coins may be counterfeit, but in the rest they are definitely real. All counterfeit coins weigh the same, all real ones too, the difference between the weights of a fake and a real coin is unknown, but it is non-zero. You have a pan scale that shows exactly the difference between the weights of the left and right pans. What is the minimum number of weighings needed to either find a bag of counterfeit coins or make sure that there are no counterfeit coins? It is also assumed that arbitrarily many coins can be obtained from each bag.

I had an idea: mark each bag with number (first bag is 1, second is 2 etc) and put on a scale 1 coin from bag 1, 2 coins from bag 2 etc, but as i think it won't help.

Comment: Also i understand, that we need only 1 weighing to determine that there are no counterfeit coins, so the problem is how many weighing do we need to determine in which bag we have counterfeit coins

Comment: I don't understand this part: 'You have a pan scale that shows exactly the difference between the weights of the left and right pans.' For me it seems like either you can measure the exact weights (simply leave one side empty) and get a number as a result of your measurement OR your scale only allows you to compare the left and right side but only tells you if they are equal or one side is heavier than the other, but with no indication of the difference between them. The problem would be quite different between the two cases.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is already quite good. Do that once, placing $250250$ coins on either side by alternatingly combining $1$ with $1000$ on one side, $2$ with $999$ on the other and so on. If the difference is zero, there are no counterfeit coins. If it’s non-zero, it’s a multiple of the difference between counterfeit and real coins. Then do the same thing again with the assignment of numbers reversed. Since the ratio of coin counts between the two weighings is different for each bag, the ratio of the differences uniquely identifies the bag of counterfeit coins.

Comment: I don't get your idea, sorry. You say that we need to put 1 coin from 1 bag on left pan, 2 coins from 2 bag on right pan, 3 coins from 3 bag on left etc? but then their weights won't be equal if there are no counterfeit coins

Comment: @niripsa You have to change the pattern (e.g. swap the alternation after $500$) to get $250250$ in each pan.  Consider $1+3+\cdots +499 + 502+504+\cdots 1000 = 2+4+\cdots +500+501+503+\cdots 999$

Comment: @niripsa: If you do it the way you propose, you wouldn't end up with what I wrote, combining $1$ and $1000$ on the same side – you'd have all odd numbers on one side and all even numbers on the other.